# Modify coco evaluation code to generate class wise accuracies

Tags: python, pytorch, object-detection, mscoco

The [cocoeval](https://github.com/cocodataset/cocoapi/blob/master/PythonAPI/pycocotools/cocoeval.py) is a goto evaluation script for calculating mAP across various IoUs. However, it doesn't provide class-wise accuracies. I'd like to use another [repository](https://github.com/Cartucho/mAP) for performing evaluation. However, the code expects two flat files. One with ground truths and another with predictions. Each line of both files should be of this format

```
<class_name> <left> <top> <right> <bottom>
```

How can I get this by modifying the cocoeval function?